# Problem with codesign. A sealed resource is missing or invalid

Tags: iphone, xcode, appstore-approval

I have been with this problem already a few days unable to solve it.

```
Whats Cool JLD$ codesign -vvvv build/Distribution-iphoneos/Whats\ cool\?.app
build/Distribution-iphoneos/Whats cool?.app: a sealed resource is missing or invalid
/Users/JLD/Desktop/iOS Development/Whats Cool/build/Distribution-iphoneos/Whats
cool?.app/Whats cool?: resource modified
```

I have tried the solutions posted on all these threads to no avail:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1590980

https://discussions.apple.com/message/9167082

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/2256-application-failed-codesign-verification.html

https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/entitlements-plist.584209/

[How to solve "Application failed codesign verification" when uploading to iTunes Connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272863/how-to-solve-application-failed-codesign-verification-when-uploading-to-itunes)

I even tried recreating the whole project again redoing all the IB connections and nothing works! It builds everything, but it is unable to code sign it! So I'm unable to upload it through the AppLoader.
I am doing all these following the instructions found at the provisioning profile on the Distribute application page.

developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/index.action

I tried building from another mac. I have my distribution profile and my distribution certificate both set to WildCard. But it still doesn't work. I made a new app under a different name with another Bundle ID to no avail. I don't know what to try anymore!

I tried to make the new project from scratch. Copying the source code and remaking all the connections on IB to no avail. I even followed this link with instructions:

http://techiechok.com/2009/03/30/resolving-iphone-code-signing-error/

But to no avail. I don't know what else to do. I'm even considering using one technical incident to solve this problem once and for all.

Everything is done now locally so there shouldn't be any problems related with symbolic links and so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS code signing fails: "A sealed resource is missing or invalid."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196309/ios-code-signing-fails-a-sealed-resource-is-missing-or-invalid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. The problem was a '?' character on the product name. Shouldn't be like that but that's how it is. Nowhere apple says that that makes a codesign verification issue.