# Application failed codesign verification during validation in Xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode, codesign

I am experiencing trouble with the distribution provisioning profile.

I have tried for many times to create a distribution provisioning profile using the instruction: http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/index.action

But when I verificate the program I get an error:

**Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate.**

I have done the steps as follows:
1.I have created certificates in key chain access.
2.I have created provisioning profiles in iOS Provisioning Portal
3.I have created an application ID
4.I have set provisioning profiles in the Code Signing section in Xcode

Besides, I have checked that there are no duplicate or out dated certificates in key chain access.

I have looked through stackoverflow and have not found a solution.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Using Keychain Access, can you verify the certificate chain for the Distribution Certificate?

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what you are talking about. I can see Distribution sertificate in my Keychain Access, but what "certificate chai" is?

Comment: Select the certificate in Keychain Access, right-click and choose 'Evaluate'. Then choose 'General' to evaluate the certificate chain. This will determine if you have the other certificates in place that validate your distribution certificate (for example, the WWDR intermediate certificate).

Comment: I have 
Evaluation Status: No root cert found
Certificate Status: Good
after Evaluation. What should i do with "No root cert found"?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have done this:

1) one Development Certificate in the iOS Provisioning Portal

2) downloaded the Development Certificate onto your Mac and installed it in on your Mac (open it, after download it, so the keychain will open and you see the Development Certificate

3) Check if in the iOS Provisioning Portal exists a Provisioning Development Provile, signed with the Certificate you added in step 2(above) in the Keychain).

4) Have you used a wilcard for the AppId, or added you a String? Under Provisioning Profiles under the row App Id there is a String like this: `**********.text`. If you have something like this `CD8V98ZN8M.*` (first characters bevore the . are different, but the star after the point is important, then you can sign with this Provisioning profile every app. If there is something like this: `CD8V98ZN8M.appname`, then your Bundlename set up in your Target in xcode must be exacrly `appname`.

5) did you download the Provisioning Profile and installed it in Xcode by moving the provisioning Profile onto the Icon?

6) Try to rebuild after made a Clean, if it still fails check the `Code signing Identity` under Bild Settings in your Application Target in xcode, what and select your Development provisioning Profile and then make a Clean and try to rebuild.

But also check out this Question: [How to solve "Application failed codesign verification" when uploading to iTunes Connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272863/how-to-solve-application-failed-codesign-verification-when-uploading-to-itunes)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem. One old version of XCode 4.2 has a bug with codesign verification, so i've just updated XCode 4.2 to newest version and my app succeeded verification. Thats it! Always check for updates! =)

Comment: If your answer solves your issue, please accept your own answer.