# How to resolve "Application failed codesign verification." when uploading Application, build with Flash Builder 4.6?

Tags: ios, flash, apache-flex, build, certificate

I have found some question which refers to my initial question :
- [on xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272863/how-to-solve-application-failed-codesign-verification-when-uploading-to-itunes)

Usually resolved in synthesis by :

- flushing certificate cache
- correcting the signing certificate ( using Distribution in replacement of Developper) C
- checking and correcting the Application ID who was sometimes not the same between the one declared in iTunes Connect and the one in the app.xml file

The fact is that I still has  the problem on Flex Builder, which is when I upload my application, it failed with "Application failed codesign verification"

I've checked these different point :

- That my certificates are installed properly
- That the Icon.png has the proper size and format of 57x57 PNG. ( after dezipping the IPA package )
- Here is the output of "codesign -dvvv ./RegimeFille.app/"

> Executable=/Users/rasata/Desktop/expot/Payload/RegimeFille.app/RegimeFille
>   Identifier=com.zra.RegimeFille
>   Format=bundle with Mach-O thin (armv7)
>   CodeDirectory v=20001 size=109624 flags=0x0(none) hashes=5473+5 location=embedded
>   Hash type=sha1 size=20
>   CDHash=d26461111925585fb6096e8fb6bcf87e32ade306
>   Signature size=4276
>   Authority=iPhone Distribution: Zo Rasatavohary
>   Authority=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
>   Authority=Apple Root CA
>   Signed Time=30 déc. 2011 18:15:03
>   Info.plist entries=37
>   Sealed Resources rules=5 files=32
>   Internal requirements count=0 size=12

Seems to me that the IPA has correctly been build,

So the question is what could still block the uploading of the application on the App Store?

How to resolve "Application failed codesign verification." when uploading Application, build with Flash Builder 4.6?

Comment: I voted to close.  It sounds to me like you have a solution; but you seem to have failed to define what your problem or ask a question. You may consider re-working this post to be more clear.

Comment: I tried to reformulate my question, does it sound more clear?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you're still lacking a description of the problem.  I think it is in the subject line?  I didn't notice that before.  You should move the subject line question into the actual content of the post.

Comment: Thank you, this made me aware that I did not use the same command line option of the question I'm referring to, which was  "codesign --verify -vvvv MyApp.app ", which give me an error of "added file : garcon.png", and a missing file :"garçon.png", So I've renamed the file "garçon.png" to "garcon.png", so I succeed in uploading the application to appstore !!! :-) Seems that there is an automatique filename conversion made by Flex Builder when building the FILE!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did have a file named : **"garçon.png"** inside my package, and after checking the Application with the command line :**" codesign --verify -vvvv MyApp.app "**, I get an error message that there was an added file named : "garcon.png", and a missing file:"garçon".png.

So the solution was to rename this file, so simple,

But anyway, I suppose that Flex Builder is automatically renaming the file inside the Package, when the name of the file include UTF-8 char ....

Thanks  0x8badf00d :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue except mine wasn't due to image naming.  When I ran codesign --verify I got a message saying the application met all the requirements and was codesigned correctly.  I don't know what the exact problem was... but when I upgraded from Snow Leopard to Lion the Application Loader took the app no problem.  Maybe it was a bug in the App Loader or the keychain.