# Please help me to create .ipa of my app

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipod, ipa

I tried last 1 day. refer all the question related my problem but can't find such a solution.
[image]

I had follow all the steps create certificates, appid, adding device id , create provision, set in the project. with this provision the app work fine in my iPhone4.

please help me
Thank you in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to solve "Application failed codesign verification" when uploading to iTunes Connect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272863/how-to-solve-application-failed-codesign-verification-when-uploading-to-itunes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In xcode 4.2 there is a totally bug for when the creating the ipa and share that time best solution find me first of all find the share bundle and then following link for the solve that problem it's rally amazing

I solve that problem while creating the project

[Reference link is here](http://sugartin.info/2011/08/11/creating-ipa-files-using-xcode4-2-using-archives/) :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to Build Settings > Code Signing and set the code signing profile automatically for each setting.  Don't just use 'Automatic'.

Answer (score 0):

there maybe problem with Entitlements file as well.

You can find it in XCode 4.2 -> Targets -> bottom section 'Entitlements'
There you can "Enable Entitlements". Other fields may be empty if the app doesn't need it.

Other codesign problems issued many time here. So you can find one of lots tutorials and remake codesign profile.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a lot of chatter on the forums (especially the Apple dev forums) that something has broken or been modified in the creation of certificates in the dev portal. All Apple dev portals are currently down (displaying the "back soon" post-it message) so hopefully this means that Apple are providing a fix.