# Problems creating an ipa file

Tags: ios, ipa

I want to create an ipa file but I get the following error message. Maybee someone knows what's going on here? Or just a hint where the error might be.

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you have changed your Code Signing Identity to a Distribution profile, rather than your Developer profile cert.  You need to explicitly create a Distribution cert in the provisioning areas of the Apple Developer website.

Here are two links that are pretty helpful, [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272863/how-to-solve-application-failed-codesign-verification-when-uploading-to-itunes) and [second](http://diaryofacodemonkey.ruprect.com/2011/03/18/ad-hoc-app-distribution-with-xcode-4/).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it may happen that Xcode Archiver fails to generate ipa file. Then here is the another option.

- Build the application.
- After successful build go to "Products" folder in your project navigator.
- Right click on it and go to "Show in Finder".
- Copy the .app file.
- Create a new folder at some other location lets say on Desktop with name "Payload".
- Paste that .app file in Payload folder.
- Zip the Payload folder.
- Rename that zipped folder with .ipa

Thats it.

Reverse procedure is used to retrieve the app file from an ipa file.

Hope this answer helps.