# Invalid Binary - Invalid Signature

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, code-signing, xcodebuild

I am trying to upload my app to iTunesConnect. But it gives me every time a invalid binary error. Then I get an e-mail saying invalid signature. I have tried everything posted in this answer: [How to solve "Application failed codesign verification" when uploading to iTunes Connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272863/how-to-solve-application-failed-codesign-verification-when-uploading-to-itunes). But I still get the error message. I triple checked everything.

[image]

[image]

I am really desperate. Hope somebody can help me. Developer support is not online yet and afterwards I have school.

Kind Regards,

Leo

Answer (score 0):

I have two possible solutions for you:

**Solution One:**
Go ahead and create a new provisioning profile and code signing identity. There could be a problem with your current profiles/identities. Also, make sure that you have valid certificates.

**Solution Two:**
You may have a problem with a redundant binary. When you upload a new version of your app to iTunes connect, it must have a new version number. For example: Joey uploads version 1.0 of his app into iTunes connect. Next time he uploads a new build he must change the version number to 1.1 or higher. If you have already uploaded at least one other build of your app, this is probably your problem. If this is your first time uploading to iTunes connect, then you probably have the issue above.

**My Advice:** This is quite an odd issue, and I'm afraid I can't think of any more solutions than the ones above. If they don't work out for you, you might want to post your question on apple's developer forums, since this seems to be an issue with iTunes connect, and not a code related issue. Apple's forums and support options will probably have more knowledge on iTunes connect than Stack Overflow since Apple's forums are solely dedicated towards the entire iOS development process.